# I want to get CPU column from task manager into CSV file but tasklist command is not giving me the CPU. How to get CPU from task manager to CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to copy CPU column from task manager into CSV file. But the command tasklist is only giving procssname, PID, memory, session name and session# and not gving CPU. Please help me with the command to get CPU usage for a process from task manager to CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Powershell command:

```
Get-Process | Export-Csv -Path c:\path\to\yourfolder\yourfile.csv
```

From [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7) documentation:

> The default display of a process is a table that includes the following columns. For a description of all of the properties of process objects, see Process Properties in the MSDN library.
>
> - Handles: The number of handles that the process has opened.
> - NPM(K): The amount of non-paged memory that the process is using, in kilobytes.
> - PM(K): The amount of pageable memory that the process is using, in kilobytes.
> - WS(K): The size of the working set of the process, in kilobytes. The working set consists of the pages of memory that were recently referenced by the process.
> - VM(M): The amount of virtual memory that the process is using, in megabytes. Virtual memory includes storage in the paging files on disk.
> - CPU(s): The amount of processor time that the process has used on all processors, in seconds.
> - ID: The process ID (PID) of the process.
> - ProcessName: The name of the process. For explanations of the concepts related to processes, see the Glossary in Help and Support Center and the Help for Task Manager.

Comment: The CPU(s) column does not show accurate values, and the `Get-Process` does not output like `tasklist`. See my answer (also in Powershell)

Comment: @WasifHasan from [tasklist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist): "Displays a list of currently running processes on the local computer or on a remote computer."; from [Get-Process](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7): "Gets the processes that are running on the local computer"

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit slow, but quite accurate in powershell:

```
tasklist /fo csv | set-content temp.csv 
Import-csv temp.csv | 
  Select-Object *,@{n='CPU %';e={$iu = $_.'Image Name'.split('.')[0]; (Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.InstanceName -eq "$iu"} | Select -Expand CookedValue}} | 
   Export-Csv "filename.csv"
Remove-Item temp.csv
```

The CPU column in `Get-Process` is in-accurate, so use `Get-Counter` instead. Replace "filename.csv" to output file.